# How to view my containers in O365 import storage account

Tags: office-365, migration

I tried migration of data from SharePoint 2013 to Office 365. When I did with my Azure account, I was able to see my containers and files in there after execution of `Set-SPOMigrationPackageAzureSource` command.

But when I tried with my Office 365 import storage account, Migration was done successfully but I don't know where to go and see the containers and files. Can I see that? If so where could I?

I used Office 365 import storage account for migration by following this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/mt210445.aspx).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just came to see a tool called 'Azure Storage Explorer'. I added my azure storage account and also Office 365 import storage account. Through this I was able to access the containers and files.

Azure Storage Explorer : https://azurestorageexplorer.codeplex.com/releases/view/125870

Please tell me if any other option is there to view without using any tool.

Answer (score 0):

You could log into your Azure subscription and navigate to your relevant Storage Account and select blobs to view the contents. Or you could use PowerShell:

```
Import-Module Azure
$subscriptionName = "YourSub"
$StorageAccount = "yourstorageaccount"
$container = 'some container'
Add-AzureAccount
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName
Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccountName $storageAccount -SubscriptionName $subscriptionName
$storageKey = (Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName $storageAccount).Primary
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccount -StorageAccountKey $storageKey
$blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container $container -context $ctx
#do something with $blobs
```